# Text to Columns permanent

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this code in Python that creates .csv files.
When I open the file I have to go to the Data tab and then Text to Columns

I then do the following as seen in these screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way I can make this permanent? I have to repeat this procedure every time I create a new .csv file.

Comment: In your last image you are delimiting on tabs and commas, are you using mixed formatting in your CSV? If it's a straight CSV it should open with the correct columns automatically.

Comment: @spikey_richie, In one of my laptop it opens them in correct columns but on the other laptop it doesn't (this one office 365 is insitalled)